# How to add Foreign Key Properties subsequently to a Code First Model?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Given the Model:

```
Public Class Customer
    Property Id() As Guid
    Property FirstName() As String
    Property MiddleName() As String
    Property LastName() As String
    Property Addresses() As ICollection(Of Address)
End Class

Public Class Address
    Property Id() As Guid
    Property Name() As String
    Property Street() As String
    Property City() As String
    Property Zip() As String
    Public Property Customer() As Customer
End Class
```

Entity Framework 6  Code First has created a column called `Customer_Id` in my table `Addresses`. Now, I'd like to add a Property `Customer_Id` to my class `Address` that represents the existing foreign key relation:

```
Public Class Address
    Property Id() As Guid
    Property Name() As String
    Property Street() As String
    Property City() As String
    Property Zip() As String
    Public Property Customer() As Customer

    //Added
    Public Property Customer_Id() As Guid

End Class
```

Unfortunately this results in an `InvalidOperationException` while creating the `DbContext` saying:

> The model backing the 'DataContext' context has changed since the database was created.

I tried different property names (with and without underscore, different casing). But still no luck. So, what is the correct way to add those properties subsequently without the need for migrations? I assume it's possible, because the model does not really change, I am only changing from an implicit declaration of a property to an explicit...

**Update:**

The responses show me, that I did not explain the problem very well. After some more reading I found the correct names now: I have an application which is installed several times at customer locations (therefore dropping and recreating the database is no option). Currently, it depends on Entity Framework's *[Independent Associations](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/05/foreign-key-vs-independent-associations-in-ef-4/)*, but I want to have the Foreign Key in my entity as well (this is no change to the model, the foreign key is already there, but does not exist as a property in my entity, since this is currently only relying on the IA instead). I did not manage to add it without EF thinking my Database is outdated.

Comment: are you sure using `SomeAddressInstance.Customer.Id` is not enough for your use ?

Comment: No. Using IAs generally seems to have drawbacks, and I am suffering some of them. Julie Lerman describes some of them (http://goo.gl/CgAwHB http://goo.gl/VX9ZE)

Answer (score 0):

This exception is because you change your model. You have to set migration strategy. Please look at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621#enabling

**(edited)**

First of all you have to remove that exception. Even if you didn't add any new column to your database your model has changed because you added new property to Address class. If you check your DB you will find **dbo.__MigrationHistory** table with **Model** column. Last (earliest) value from that column is used for checking that your model and DB are compatible. I'm not sure but I think that EF stores there binary serialized model. So the solution is - recreate DB or add migration (probably empty migration).

**(edited)**

When you want to set FK you can do this very simple by Data Annotations

```
// c# example
public class Address
{
    ...
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

}
```

or in fluent api

```
// c# example
modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
    .HasRequired(arg => arg.Customer)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(arg => arg.CustomerId);
```

or look at:

http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/01/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx

Comment: No, you got me wrong. The foreign key property should not be added, but only to be made explicit, since it already exists because of EF's conventions in the database. I am only missing the CustomerId property in my model class.

Comment: Ok, I see. But first of all you have to remove that exception. Remove old DB, add migration, upgrade by package manager console, whatever... Your model and DB should be in the same version.

Comment: Sure, this is an option in my development environment, but what should i tell the customers?

Answer (score 0):

for me two ways :

- `drop table __MigrationHistory` : that is have the new model runs, but forget migration functionalities
- create a new db by changing the connection string of the application. Replace old __MigrationHistory by __MigrationHistory of the newly created db

Never tested the second solution, but it should work.

**Before using any solution**:
backup you db.

**Before using first solution**: are you sure you will never need migration functionalities ?